# Replace object function using polymorphism

Tags: c#, types

I have code using a lot of `else if` statements for converting types.

Is there way to replace `Bitconverter.ToInt32()` based on type using T?

```
foreach(FieldInfo f in fields)
{
  if(f == typeof(System.Int16))
    num = Bitconverter.ToInt16(bytearr,0)
  else if (f == typeof(System.Int32))
    num = Bitconverter.ToInt32(bytearr,0)
  else if ( ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? This pseudo-code is not very helpful either. Show your attempts and explain how they aren't working

Comment: can you please post a sample input and expected output? what is `stuff` ? Up to now I am more confused than intriguied by your question

Comment: you can try through reflection

Comment: @sifavahora: You can do almost anything with reflection. OP is asking for a solution *better* than the one he has. I'm pretty sure reflection doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 1):

The term polymorphism is may be not appropriate in this context, since you don't have inheritance in you code. A solution using generics like `<T>` does not come instantly into my mind, but here is a hacky attempt to remove the if/else construct using reflection:

```
public static object ConvertByteArrayToValueType(Type type, byte [] bytearr) 
{
    if (type.IsValueType) // if you have a value type (BitConverter can handle only those)
    {
        // find the proper method based on the type name
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("To" + type.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (mi != null)
        {
            return mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { bytearr, 0 }); // call the proper method
        }
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Here is a little test program to show how it works:

```
public class TEST 
{
    public short Short;
    public int Integer;
    public bool boolean;
}

void Main()
{
    byte[] bytearr = new byte[] {1,1,1,1};

    FieldInfo [] fields = typeof(TEST).GetFields();

    object num = 0;

    foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
    {       
        num = ConvertByteArrayToValueType(f.FieldType, bytearr);            
        Console.WriteLine(num);  
    }
}
```

I guess since you don't know the type in `fields` in advance and you are assigning the conversion result always to the same variable it should be of type  `object`.

Also: the if condition will not work as they are now in your post. You need to compare the `FieldType` like this:

```
if(f.FieldType == typeof(System.Int16))
```

Comment: yes thanks i forgot to write if(f.FieldType == typeof(System.Int16))...

But im worry about performance using reflection now....

Comment: @FDDHam if you worry about performance you should create a loop of 100000 iterations, stop the time and calculate the average computing time. Then you can see it for yourself. Reflection is not always that slow... :)

Comment: @FDDHam Here is a benchmark: for 100000 iterations with a `TEST` class with 20 Fields on average the conversion of all fields needs `0,00011` milliseconds and in sum `11` on a Pentium i7 2.1 Ghz. Tested in Linqpad